# NestJs DTO's inheritance and methods

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am working with NestJs and trying to follow the DRY concept, which mean I don't want to repeat myself over and over. Here is the thing : I'm using DTO's in my controllers, which I want to convert to objects before sending it to my services.

For example, my controller receives a CreateUserDto, I convert it to User and then ask my service to do the job.

At first I wanted to write an abstract Dto class, containing a toEntity() method that would return the right object using plainToInstance. Sadly, this one doesn't work with generics, so I'm stuck here. I made a compromise, and decided to implement toEntity() in each DTO's. Here is the thing, I always have a CreateDto and an UpdateDto (which extends PartialType(CreateDto).
But then when I try to call updateDto.toEntity(), it tolds me that it is not a function.. Is there a way to have the inherited method inside my UpdateDto ?

Some code samples :

**create-user.dto.ts**

```
import { instanceToPlain, plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';
import { IBaseDto } from 'src/common/core/interfaces/base-dto.abstract';
import { User } from '../schemas/user.schema';

export class CreateUserDto implements IBaseDto<User> {
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string;

  toEntity(): User {
    const data = instanceToPlain(this);
    return plainToInstance(User, data);
  }
}
```

**update-user.dto.ts**

```
import { PartialType } from '@nestjs/mapped-types';
import { CreateUserDto } from './create-user.dto';

export class UpdateUserDto extends PartialType(CreateUserDto) {}
```

Comment: Have you found a good way to handle this issue? NestJS folks seem to be silent on this one.